# Windows 8 says I have a touchscreen but in Device Manager it does not show a touch screen

Tags: windows-8

My laptop does not have a touchscreen according to its specs and device manager. In the System Window though it shows that I have a limited two point touchscreen and the virtual keyboard button appears in system tray due to that.

[This is my laptop](http://bit.ly/1BmuS2l)

Am I missing something? Does it really have a touchscreen? If it doesn't how do force Windows 8 to stop telling me that I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds a lot like some quirk with the touchpad driver, possibly to enable gestures.

A touchscreen should typically show up as a standard screen, but should also have its own USB/HID entry.

Just right click your taskbar, point on the topmost option and disable the virtual keyboard bar, which will remove the button once again.

Comment: yeah, but my touchpad supports up to four fingers while system says two points... anw, I suppose I should just ignore it

Comment: @JohnDemetriou Check the drivers, maybe it has two modes of operation. E.g. my Wacom tablet has two modes, either as a touchscreen device or as a classic touchpad. Both modes will cause Windows to behave differently.